How can I abbreviate phrases using Polars built-in methods?
I need to abbreviate a series or expression of phrases by extracting the capitalized words and then creating an abbreviation based on their proportional lengths.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Extract capitalized words from each phrase.
Calculate proportional lengths based on the total length of the capitalized words in each phrase.
Adjust the lengths to ensure the abbreviation meets a target length (e.g., 4 characters).

TODO: If the abbreviation results in duplicates, I need to either:

Automatically resolve them (e.g., by adding numbers or modifying characters)
Flag them with a warning.

Currently, I’m using a Python function and mapping it across a Polars Series.
Is there a more efficient way to do it using Polars built-in methods.
Here's my current approach:
import polars as pl


def _abbreviate_phrase(phrase: str, length: int) -> str:
    """Abbreviate a single phrase by a constant length.

    The function aims to abbreviate phrases into a constant length by focusing
    on capitalized words and adjusting them according to their proportional lengths.

    Example:
        phrase = 'Commercial & Professional'
        length = 4
        res = _abbreviate_phrase(phrase, length)
        print(res)
        # CoPr
    """
    # determine size of slices
    capitalized_words = [word for word in phrase.split(' ') if word[0].isupper()]
    word_lengths = [len(word) for word in capitalized_words]
    total_word_length = sum(word_lengths)

    if total_word_length == 0:
        return ''  # Return empty if no capitalized words

    proportional_lengths = [round(wl / total_word_length * length) for wl in word_lengths]
    total_proportional_length = sum(proportional_lengths)

    # Adjust slices if their total length doesn't match target length
    if total_proportional_length < length:
        for i in range(length - total_proportional_length):
            proportional_lengths[i] += 1
    elif total_proportional_length > length:
        for i in range(total_proportional_length - length):
            proportional_lengths[i] -= 1

    # Combine the abbreviated words and return the result
    abbreviated_phrase = ''.join([word[:plength] for word, plength in zip(capitalized_words, proportional_lengths)])
    return abbreviated_phrase


def abbreviate_phrases(phrases: pl.Series, length: int) -> pl.Series:
    """Abbreviate phrases by a constant length.

    Example:
        phrases = pl.Series([
            'Sunshine',
            'Sunset',
            'Climate Change and Environmental Impact',
            'Health and Wellness',
            'Quantum Computing and Physics',
            'Global Warming and Renewable Resources'
        ])
        length = 4
        res = abbreviate_phrases(phrases, length)
        print(res)
        # Series: '' [str]
        # [
        #   "Suns"
        #   "Suns"
        #   "CEnI"
        #   "HeWe"
        #   "QCoP"
        #   "GWRR"
        # ]
    """
    abbreviates = phrases.map_elements(lambda x: _abbreviate_phrase(x, length), return_dtype=pl.String)
    # if not abbreviates.is_unique().all():
    #     print('WARNING: There are duplicated abbreviations.')
    return abbreviates

Edit: performance comparison setup for proposed solutions
import sys
import timeit

def generate_phrases(n: int) -> pl.DataFrame:
    # Repeat the original phrases 'n' times
    phrases = pl.DataFrame({
        "p": ['Climate Change and Environmental Impact',
              'Health and Wellness',
              'Quantum Computing and Physics',
              'Global Warming and Renewable Resources',
              'no capital letters']
    })
    return pl.concat([phrases.with_columns(pl.col('p')+'_'+str(i)) for i in range(n)])

def compare_performance(n: int, length: int = 4):
    phrases = generate_phrases(n)

    abbreviate_phrases_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: abbreviate_phrases(phrases['p'], length), number=10)
    abbreviate_phrases_harbeck_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: abbreviate_phrases_harbeck(phrases, phrase_column="p", length=length), number=10)
    abbreviate_phrases_jqurious_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: abbreviate_phrases_jqurious(phrases['p'], length=length), number=10)
    abbreviate_phrases_rle_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: abbreviate_phrases_rle(phrases['p'], length=length), number=10)

    ratio_harbeck = abbreviate_phrases_time / abbreviate_phrases_harbeck_time
    ratio_jqurious = abbreviate_phrases_time / abbreviate_phrases_jqurious_time
    ratio_rle = abbreviate_phrases_time / abbreviate_phrases_rle_time

    return ratio_harbeck, ratio_jqurious, ratio_rle

Edit: performance comparison results for proposed solutions
n = 200_000
ratio_harbeck, ratio_jqurious, ratio_rle = compare_performance(n=n, length=4)

print(f"Performance ratio ({n*5} rows):")
print(f"    original/harbeck {ratio_harbeck:.2f}x")
print(f"    original/jqurious {ratio_jqurious:.2f}x")
print(f"    original/rle {ratio_rle:.2f}x")
print()
print(f'python {sys.version.split(' ')[0]}')
print(f'polars {pl.__version__}')

# Performance ratio (1000000 rows):
#     original/harbeck 0.70x
#     original/jqurious 1.30x
#     original/rle 1.79x

# python 3.12.0
# polars 1.12.0


It is possible, but it's probably not an ideal task to perform this way.
This is the fastest approach I've found so far. It runs ~2.5x faster for me with  1_000_000 phrases. (1.5s vs 3.9s)
def abbreviate_phrases(s: pl.Series, length: int = 4):
    phrases = pl.col(s.name)
    is_upper = pl.element().filter(pl.element().str.contains(r"^\p{Upper}"))
    words = phrases.list.eval(is_upper)

    len_chars = phrases.list.eval(is_upper.str.len_chars())
    total_len = len_chars.list.sum()

    proportion_len = (
        (len_chars / total_len * length)
          .list.eval(pl.element().round().cast(int))
          .alias("proportion_len")
    )

    total_proportion_len = (
        (pl.col("proportion_len").list.sum() - length)
           .alias("total_proportion_len")
    )
    
    adjustments = (
        pl.concat_list(
            (-pl.col("total_proportion_len"))
              .repeat_by(pl.col("total_proportion_len").abs()),
            pl.lit(0)
              .repeat_by(
                  pl.col("proportion_len").list.len() 
                  - (pl.col("total_proportion_len").abs())
              )
        )
    )

    return (
        s
        .to_frame()
        .with_row_index()
        .with_columns(phrases.str.split(" "))
        .with_columns(words, proportion_len)
        .with_columns(total_proportion_len)
        .with_columns(pl.col("proportion_len") + adjustments)
        .explode(pl.exclude("index", "total_proportion_len"))
        .with_columns(phrases.str.slice(0, pl.col("proportion_len")))
        .group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
        .agg(phrases)
        .select(phrases.list.join(""))
        .to_series()
    )

Some observations:

adjustments seems to be the most expensive operation and takes ~50% of the runtime.

.agg().select(phrases.list.join("")) was considerably faster than .agg(phrases.str.join()) which was surprising.



Update: Slightly faster version of adjustments using .rle() (this goes from 1.5s to 1.0s for me)
(inspired by the when/then approach from @HenryHarbeck's answer)
def abbreviate_phrases_rle(s: pl.Series, length = 4):
    phrases = pl.col(s.name)
    is_upper = pl.element().filter(pl.element().str.contains(r"^\p{Upper}"))
    words = phrases.list.eval(is_upper)

    word_lengths = phrases.list.eval(is_upper.str.len_chars())
    total_length = word_lengths.list.sum()

    proportional_length = (
        (word_lengths / total_length * length)
          .list.eval(pl.element().round().cast(int))
          .alias("proportional_length")
    )

    length_diff = (
        (pl.col("proportional_length").list.sum() - length)
           .alias("length_diff")
    )
    
    rle = (
        pl.int_ranges(pl.col("index").rle().struct.field("len"))
          .flatten()
    )
    
    adjustments = (
        pl.when(
           pl.col("length_diff") != 0, pl.col("length_diff").abs() > rle
        )
        .then(pl.when(pl.col("length_diff") < 0).then(1).otherwise(-1))
        .otherwise(0)
    )      

    return (
        s
        .to_frame()
        .with_row_index()
        .with_columns(phrases.str.split(" "))
        .with_columns(words, proportional_length)
        .with_columns(length_diff)
        .explode(pl.exclude("index", "length_diff"))
        .with_columns(phrases.str.slice(0, pl.col("proportional_length") + adjustments))
        .group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
        .agg(phrases)
        .select(phrases.list.join(""))
        .to_series()
    )

Polars plugins
To do this "really" efficiently, you'd likely need to implement it in Rust as a Polars Plugin.
If I take the parallel pig latinify example as a template. (I'm a Rust beginner, so may have missed some things.)
use polars_utils::cache::FastFixedCache;
use pyo3_polars::export::polars_core::export::regex::Regex;

fn abbreviate_str(value: &str, reg: &mut Regex, output: &mut String) {
    let max_len = 4;
    let mut total_len = 0;
    let mut word_lengths = vec![];

    let mut words = vec![];

    if value.len() > 0 {
        for word in value.split_whitespace() {
            if reg.is_match(word) {
                let word_len = word.chars().count();
                total_len += word_len;
                word_lengths.push(word_len);
                words.push(word);
            }
        }

        let mut total_proportional_len = 0;
        let mut proportional_lengths: Vec<_> = word_lengths
            .iter()
            .map(|wl| {
                let prop_len = (*wl as f64 / total_len as f64 * max_len as f64).round() as usize;
                total_proportional_len += prop_len;
                prop_len
            })
            .collect();

        if total_proportional_len > max_len {
            let diff = total_proportional_len - max_len;
            for idx in 0..diff {
                proportional_lengths[idx] -= 1
            }
        } else if total_proportional_len < max_len {
            let diff = max_len - total_proportional_len;
            for idx in 0..diff {
                proportional_lengths[idx] += 1
            }
        }

        words
            .iter()
            .zip(proportional_lengths.iter())
            .for_each(|(word, prop_len)| {
                let end = match word.char_indices().map(|(idx, _)| idx).nth(*prop_len) {
                    Some(end) => end,
                    _ => word.len(),
                };
                write!(output, "{}", &word[..end])
                .unwrap()
            })
    }
}

#[polars_expr(output_type=String)]
fn abbreviate_with_parallelism(
    inputs: &[Series],
    context: CallerContext,
    //kwargs: PigLatinKwargs,
) -> PolarsResult<Series> {
    use rayon::prelude::*;
    let ca = inputs[0].str()?;

    let pat = r"^\p{Upper}";
    if context.parallel() {
        let mut reg_cache = FastFixedCache::new(1);
        let out: StringChunked = ca.apply_into_string_amortized(|value, output| {
            let reg = reg_cache
                .try_get_or_insert_with(pat, |p| Regex::new(p))
                .unwrap();
            abbreviate_str(value, reg, output)
        });
        Ok(out.into_series())
    } else {
        POOL.install(|| {
            let n_threads = POOL.current_num_threads();
            let splits = split_offsets(ca.len(), n_threads);

            let chunks: Vec<_> = splits
                .into_par_iter()
                .map(|(offset, len)| {
                    let mut reg_cache = FastFixedCache::new(1);
                    let sliced = ca.slice(offset as i64, len);
                    let out = sliced.apply_into_string_amortized(|value, output| {
                        let reg = reg_cache
                            .try_get_or_insert_with(pat, |p| Regex::new(p))
                            .unwrap();
                        abbreviate_str(value, reg, output)
                    });
                    out.downcast_iter().cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>()
                })
                .collect();

            Ok(
                StringChunked::from_chunk_iter(ca.name().clone(), chunks.into_iter().flatten())
                    .into_series(),
            )
        })
    }
}

For comparison, this runs in 0.1s (for 10 million rows I get 1.1s vs 16.1s)

https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/plugins/your-first-polars-plugin/

https://marcogorelli.github.io/polars-plugins-tutorial/stringify/



Hi @jqurious, thank you for your great proposal. I implemented your approach and measured a speedup of around 20%, which is a bit less than the 2.5x improvement you saw. I suspect that the difference might be hardware dependent, but it’s definitely a significant improvement.

@Oyibo Yeah, benchmarking is "hard" as they say. There have been some examples of people getting opposite results depending on hardware/OS in some previous questions. I've added a slightly faster version. Also, I just noticed "Federal I white mind." generates different results. It seems round(0.5) in Python is 0 but in Polars (Rust) it is 1. Have to read up on why they differ and adjust the answer.

That's awesome @jqurious! Thank you very much for your effort. These solutions are really instructive beyond the actual topic. I’ll implement the RLE version and add it to the performance comparison above. Rust uses "round half away from zero",  while Python uses "round half to even" as rounding strategies. It's easy to miss the distinction!

Yeah, apparently Rust added round_ties_even() which Polars does not seem to currently expose via its API: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/17798

Here you go
phrases = pl.DataFrame({
    "p": [
        'Sunshine',
        'Sunset',
        'Climate Change and Environmental Impact',
        'Health and Wellness',
        'Quantum Computing and Physics',
        'Global Warming and Renewable Resources',
        "no capital letters",
    ]
})

def abbreviate_phrase(df: pl.DataFrame, *, phrase_column: pl.Expr | str) -> pl.DataFrame:
    if isinstance(phrase_column, str):
        phrase_column = pl.col(phrase_column)

    # cap_words defined below
    word_lengths = pl.col("cap_words").str.len_chars()
    total_word_length = word_lengths.sum().over("index")
    proportional_lengths = (word_lengths / total_word_length * length).round()
    total_proportional_length = pl.col("proportional_lengths").sum().over("index")
    length_diff = length - total_proportional_length
    proportion_adjustment = pl.when(length_diff < 0).then(-1).otherwise(1)
    slice_length = (
        proportional_lengths + (
            pl.when(
                length_diff != 0,
                length_diff.abs() == pl.col("index").cum_count().over("index"),
            )
            .then(proportion_adjustment)
            .otherwise(0)
        )
    )
    
    output = (
        df
        .with_row_index()
        .with_columns(cap_words=phrase_column.str.extract_all("[A-Z]\w+"))
        .explode("cap_words")
        .with_columns(proportional_lengths=proportional_lengths)
        .with_columns(sliced=pl.col("cap_words").str.slice(0, slice_length))
        .group_by("index")
        .agg(
            phrase_column.first(),
            abbreviates=pl.col("sliced").str.join(""),
        )
        .drop("index")
    )

    if not output.filter(output.select("abbreviates").is_duplicated()).is_empty():
        print('WARNING: There are duplicated abbreviations.')
    
    return output


print(abbreviate_phrase(phrases, phrase_column="p"))

WARNING: There are duplicated abbreviations.
shape: (7, 2)
┌─────────────────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ p                               ┆ abbreviates │
│ ---                             ┆ ---         │
│ str                             ┆ str         │
╞═════════════════════════════════╪═════════════╡
│ Sunshine                        ┆ Suns        │
│ Sunset                          ┆ Suns        │
│ Climate Change and Environment… ┆ CEnI        │
│ Health and Wellness             ┆ HeWe        │
│ Quantum Computing and Physics   ┆ QCoP        │
│ Global Warming and Renewable R… ┆ GWRR        │
│ no capital letters              ┆             │
└─────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘


Thank you, @Henry Harbeck, for your pure Polars solution! It's a great starting point. I noticed that you forgot to include the "length" argument. Would you mind editing your solution to include it? The performance of abbreviate_phrases_harbeck is about 30-40% slower than the original when tested on 1 million rows. I hope I measured it correctly...
